# 2d-array error with the length

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am having some truble in this part of the code **cols = input[0].length() ;** it says to me that 
1) cannot invoke length of the primitive type of int 
2)length cannot be resolved or is not field.
i am doning a code for minesweeper game and here i want to fill the grid with the index from the file I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner file = new Scanner ("in.txt");

    int line=0;
    int m = file.nextInt();
    int n = file.nextInt();
    int index = file.nextInt();

    int [][] input = new int[m][n];
    String.valueOf(input);

    for (int [] field : input) {
        printMineField(field);
    }
    file.close();
    line= line++;
}

private static void printMineField(int[] input) {


    int rows = input.length, cols = input[0].length ;
    int[][] grid = new int[rows][cols];


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(grid[i], 0);
    }
    //
}
```

Comment: Hint: Java isn't JavaScript. No point in double tagging. And then length is a field on arrays - not a method. So drop the () - and do spend some research on such basics before asking other questions.

Comment: I am new to java and i am doing my best

Comment: Yes. But again : this is super basic and you are expected to do some real research prior posting here. Hint: anything you can dream of asking at this point of your learning curve has been ask here. And answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `length` is a field in array, not a function. So you should use `cols = input[0].length;` - remove those parenthesis.

Next, You are passing one dimensional array to your method. You should pass a two dimensional array.

Replace

```
private static void printMineField(int[] input)
```

with:

```
private static void printMineField(int[][] input)
```

Then you will also need to replace

```
for (int [] field : input) {
    printMineField(field);
}
```

with:

```
printMineField(input);
```

Comment: i did it but still having an error " cannot invoke length on the array type int[]"

Comment: what error are you getting and where are you getting it?

Comment: this is the error cannot invoke length on the array type int[] and i am getting it on this line int rows = input.length, cols = input[0].length() ;

Comment: Use `cols = input[0].length` - remove those parenthesis.